# AWS eb create django-env error NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to deploy my django project online.
I followed aws doc available at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html
but when I got to `eb create django-env` section  it gives me the following error

```
`ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. Access Denied`
```

But I noticed in a tutorial in youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZOzTFOMh0I at the point of

```
`eb init -p python-3.8 django-tutotrial`
```

the aws-access-id was entered. But on the one at aws doc there was nothing provided.

Please how can i go about that. Any help would be appreciated

**Update**
I have created user roles on my aws account and I already have the credentials on my local machine. but how to put the credentials on the deployment is the issue.

Comment: Have you confirmed permissions of the user/role being used when you're running `eb create`?

Comment: @markwalker_ how do I confirm that and if I have not done that, how can I grant the permissions, would it be on my local system or on the aws account

Comment: @markwalker_  I have created user roles on my aws account and I already have the credentials on my local machine. but how to put the credentials on the deployment is the issue.

Comment: If your credentials file is in the usual place(s), it knows where to look. If you're using python like in the examples, boto knows where to find your credentials and you shouldn't need to do anything with them

Comment: @markwalker_ please i do not know about any location. Please wht location am i supposed o put my credentials?

Comment: I use a mac, so for me I have a folder in my home directory (`~/.aws`) and in there is a file called `credentials` which contains my `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`. It looks like the eb cli probably sets this up for you, but it's worth looking into this and then checking the permissions for the account you're using. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html

Comment: @markwalker_ I am using windows, I installed aws cli and it was saved inside my program files, I was able to set the credentials but the eb cli still did not stop the error. This is really frustrating I have been working on this section for days now.

Comment: I just discovered that location of my .aws file was in c:\user\my computer\.aws directory and the credential file is located there. but eb cli is not working with it. I would try and see what else I can do to get the eb cli to identify the credentials and get back. Any help that u might still render I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: @markwalker_ Thanks, for the response. While I was digging deeper into the aws I discorvered that the user which I was trying to use, its last activity changes anytime I run `eb create` so it shows that the credentials were working but somehow there was no authorization. I am currently confused as to what to do.

Comment: Currently going through the same process, it's amazing that a company as big as Amazon can't even keep their 'getting started' tutorials up to date.